# Un artículo definido solo con un nombre de una persona

Tags: gramática

En una película "Hogar" (España) observé la siguiente oración:

"*Ha sido una semana jodida. **El** Toni y yo hemos cortado.*"

Nunca he visto el uso de un artículo definido con solo un nombre de persona (sin ningún adjetivo o "el señor").

¿Por qué se usó el artículo?

Para aclarar el contexto...esto fue dicho en un grupo de ayuda a los alcohólicos anónimos en el que una mujer estaba hablando sobre su progreso.

P.s. Por adelantado les agradecería que corregieran los errores en mi letra, en caso de que los haya.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Los respuestas ahí son suficientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/el):

> 4. Uso con antropónimos. En la lengua culta, los nombres propios de persona se emplean normalmente sin artículo: *Juan es un tipo simpático; No he visto a María desde el mes pasado*. **La anteposición del artículo, en estos casos, suele ser propia del habla popular**: «Un señor mayor chiquiaba mucho a la María» (Medina Cosas [Méx. 1990]). **No obstante, hay zonas del ámbito hispánico, por ejemplo en Chile, donde esta anteposición se da también en el habla culta, habitualmente en registros coloquiales y especialmente ante nombres de mujer**: «Creo que las mujeres siguen siendo estupendas periodistas. Está la Patricia Verdugo, la Patricia Politzer» (Hoy [Chile] 8-14.12.97).